# Stuck in Encryption Mode

Tags: encryption

I have an Android 4.0.1 10" tablet. I started encryption last night around 5:30pm. It is now 7:40 am the following morning and I still see the "green" Android icon on the screen. I had just bought the tablet three days ago.

How long does it take for the encryption process? Is something broken? Is there a way to fix it? I have about twelve to fourteen apps on my device, nothing more.

Please help...

Thank you

Comment: Can you provide more clues on this? Define green android icon - are you talking about on starting up of the device and that is what you're seeing prior to the familiar android environment?

Answer (score 1):

This is overly long, and something is most likely wrong.

I would say pull the battery, and then wipe the userdata. You may not need to wipe the userdata, but if the encryption has failed at some point then it will be necessary.